# std::vector<int>::erase failed in compilation

Tags: c++, vector

I have a piece of code where I first define the

```
std::vector<int> half_gid_m;
```

I compute the elements of the vector half_gid_m by the function push_back.
Afterwards I perform the function sort and unique on the vector:

```
sort(half_gid_m.begin(),half_gid_m.end());
std::vector<int>::iterator itv( std::unique(half_gid_m.begin(),half_gid_m.end()) );
```

Finally, I erase the part of the vector with repeated entries with

```
half_gid_m.erase(itv,half_gid_m.end());
```

It seems that everything is right, but the compilation gives me this strange kind of error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>    >::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:110: note: candidates are: typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:122: note:                 typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
//home/gales/ingv/p-gales/simulations/little_mesh/lib/p-gales/include/gales-0.1/gales/map/map_rule.hpp:166: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&) const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:110: note: candidates are: typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:122: note:                 typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::erase(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >) [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]
```

I really cannot understand where the problem is since the vector, the push_back, sort and unique operations are written in the right way.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you include `<vector>` and `<algorithm>`

Comment: -1: [Cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/qhkyNX)

Comment: Please post a complete test case to demonstrate the problem. Are you doing this all in one function? It looks like `half_gid_m` is `const` when you try to erase from it - perhaps it's a class member, and you're sorting it in a non-`const` member function, then trying to erase from it in a `const` function?

Answer (score 5):

In essense it says `error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector::erase(...) const`. I.e. you are calling `erase` on a constant vector and `erase` is a non-const member function. Make the vector non-const.

Comment: +1 for nice point from damn error messages >o<